# How to verify when AI can win [Tic-Tac-Toe] Android Studio

Tags: java, android, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe

i'm kinda stuck here, how can I verify when AI can win in Tic-Tac-Toe more efficient than all the posibilites like if (1,1)and (1,2) is O he can win by choosing (1,3), i mean like this:

Before the code i wanna clarify something:
Btz1-9 are the 9 spaces where you can write X or O.

```
Btz1-Btz2-Btz3
Btz4-Btz5-Btz6
Btz7-Btz8-Btz9
```

IF:

```
Btz5 = 2 ---> The space is empty.
Btz5 = 1 ---> The space is X (player)
Btz5 = 0 ---> The space is O (bot)
```

.

```
if (btz1 == 0 && btz2 == 0) {
Verify if btz 3 it's 2

} else if (btz2 == 0 && btz3 == 0) {
Verify if btz 1 it's 2

} else if (btz4 == 0 && btz5 == 0) {
Verify if btz 6 it's 2

} else if (btz5 == 0 && btz6 == 0) {
blah blah

} else if (btz7 == 0 && btz8 == 0) {
blah blah

} else if (btz8 == 0 && btz9 == 0) {
blah blah

} else if (btz1 == 0 && btz4 == 0) {
blah blah

} else if (btz2 == 0 && btz5 == 0) {
blah blah

} else if (btz3 == 0 && btz6 == 0) {
blah blah

} else if (btz4 == 0 && btz7 == 0) {
blah blah

} else if (btz5 == 0 && btz8 == 0) {
blah blah

} else if (btz6 == 0 && btz9 == 0) {
blah blah

} else if (btz1 == 0 && btz5 == 0) {
blah blah

} else if (btz5 == 0 && btz9 == 0) {
blah blah

} else if (btz3 == 0 && btz5 == 0) {
blah blah

} else if (btz5 == 0 && btz7 == 0) {
blah blah

} else if (btz3 == 0 && btz7 == 0) {
blah blah

} else if (btz1 == 0 && btz9 == 0) {
blah blah

} else {

Just chose a random number.
```

I hope you can understand something from that. Thank you

Comment: I'm marking this post as `Requires Editing`. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so that your question can be answered.

Comment: I'd mark it as `Requires Research`. Google is full of examples/tutorials on how to write a decent Tic-Tac-Toe on Android.

Comment: I already used that method instead, thank you anyway. :)

Comment: Tic-tac-toe is a game where you can always win/draw. I don't think that you really need alot of fancy stuff :) It might be useless, like you said, to specify / generate the whole tree for every game, but it might be a good idea, to generate it once. and try to find a solution via a search trough that tree. (dept-first) e.g.